# Resources Not showing in Designer View Visual Studio Windows Phone Application

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml, design-view

All the strings which I am taking from External Resource File is not showing up in designer View. But When I run my application it shows that string.

My application is working but If it starts showing these texts in design view then I don't have to run application every time in my phone to check that texts.

I think there must be a setting for this if it is possible to do that.

I couldn't find anything related to it on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designer does not invoke Resource files.

Here's now I do it:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="Header" Text="~Header" />
```

In this code, the value of Text is written by the localized Resource file but in the designer it shows "~Header" as a placeholder when it's not running.

// Best of luck!

Comment: Thats a little bit disappointing to hear. As well it would be nice if the uid would be checked by the compiler or autocomplete in the designer would work for it.